# DELETE sql statement in php doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I hava a problem deleting a row in database using SQL query in PHP, I've tried to find out if my code is wrong and I've tried re-factoring my code many times but I still have problem with my **SQL code**

here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['del'])){
    $cn = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(!$cn){
        echo "Cannot connect to MySQL server<br>";
        exit;
    }
    mysql_select_db("Logistic");
    $pid = (int)$_POST['pid'];
    if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM product WHERE product.PID = '$pid'")){
        mysql_close($cn);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Delete product ID:' . $pid . ' successfully");
                history.go(-1);
              </script>';
    } else {
        mysql_close($cn);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Delete product ID:' . $pid . ' error");
                history.go(-1);
              </script>';
    }
}
?>
```

When I run this PHP, the statement
 `mysql_query("DELETE FROM product WHERE product.PID = '$pid'")` 
**turn out to be FALSE all the time**, even if there's a row that has product.PID = '$pid'

I welcome any advice and thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe try `DELETE * FROM product WHERE product.PID = '$pid' LIMIT 1`

Comment: mysql_query extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: check for error during selecting database pal. May be it is a source of error

Comment: I think You should not give space between product.PID='$pid'. I mean try this one

"DELETE FROM product WHERE product.PID='$pid' "

Comment: @HujjatNazari Rizier123 "whereof one does not know..."!!

Comment: please print the query before you use it. you can print this echo "DELETE FROM product WHERE product.PID = '$pid'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you receiving pid from URL.You can debug your code to find the problem.
If you are receiving pid then there may be a problem in query.

```
if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM product WHERE product.PID = '$pid'") or die(mysql_error())){....
```

It will print mysql error and exit the program.
You can use print_r($_POST) to print all the post variables coming to the page.

Comment: thank you very much, the problem is not the code. The 'product' table and other related tables in my database are set ON DELETE NO ACTION as default

Answer (score 0):

Your code simply says sucess alway.

You can put the deletion check using mysql_affected_rows() count >=1.

working code.

```
    <html>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name ="pidpid" />
<input type="submit" name ="del" id="del" value="Delete"/>

</form>
</html>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['del'])){
echo "1";
    $cn = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(!$cn){
        echo "Cannot connect to MySQL server<br>";
        exit;
    }
    mysql_select_db("Logistic");
    $pid = (int)$_POST['pidpid'];

    $str="DELETE FROM product WHERE product.PID = '$pid'";
    echo $str;
    mysql_query($str);
    $delChk=mysql_affected_rows();
    echo $delChk;

    if ($delChk>=1){
        mysql_close($cn);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Delete product ID:' . $pid . ' successfully");
                history.go(-1);
              </script>';
    } else {
        mysql_close($cn);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Delete product ID:' . $pid . ' error");
                history.go(-1);
              </script>';
    }
}
?>
```